# Displaying opendir results in a select list alphabetically

Tags: php, alphabetical, opendir

I'm populating a select element with the following :

```
<?php
      $files2 = opendir(WAVEFORM_RELATIVE_PATH);
      while (false!==($READ=readdir($files2))) {
        if (in_array(substr(strtolower($READ),-4),array('.png'))) {
            echo '<option'.($TRACKS->waveform==$READ ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$READ.'</option>'."\n";
        }
      }
      closedir($files2);
      ?>
```

At the moment it's returning the results in a totally random order. How do I make the list display in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to use [`scandir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). You can specify a sort order using `SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING` (`0`) or `SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING` (`1`):

```
$files2 = scandir(WAVEFORM_RELATIVE_PATH, SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING);
foreach($files2 as $file) {
    if (in_array(substr(strtolower($file), -4), array('.png'))) {
        echo '<option'.($TRACKS->waveform==$file? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$file.'</option>'."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't return any results in my drop down list. Empty dir? It may be because the original routine is reading which option has been previously selected and stored and this one doesn't look like it is? Or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: this was just an example to show how `scandir` works. i don't know the purpose of your code or how it's supposed to work. maybe try echoing out `$file` in the loop to make sure the files in the directory are actually being read into `$file2`.

Comment: Brilliant, that did the job. Thanks so much ;)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can store the filename in an array, sort the array and then use them in select options

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use [glob](http://php.net/glob).

```
$files = glob(WAVEFORM_RELATIVE_PATH.'/*.png');
sort($files);
foreach($files as $file)
    echo '<option....>'.$file.'</option>';
```